# Drools decision table - one column - two fields

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor, guvnor

Let's suppose we have some class which is related to one or more codes: main and secondary. Every object of this class has at least main code and can have unlimited number of secondary codes:

```
class Something {

  private String mainCode;
  private List<String> secondaryCodes;
}
```

I want to make a rule in Drools decision table which allows me to check if value given in column is equal to mainCode or is contained by secondaryCodes. 
So I need one column for two rules related to two different fields.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

The constraint can be written as a compound Boolean expression:

```
mainCode == $param || secondaryCodes contains $param
```

There's no restriction as to the fields you refer to in such an expression.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still don't know how to do it in Guvnor. Maybe I wasn't clear about this.

Comment: I tried many things here and I always get two columns to fill.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Guvnor using @{param} in a Condition BRL fragment like:

```
  $s : Something (maincode == "@{codes}" || secondaryCodes contains "@{codes}"
```

That gives you one column.
-J